# dynamical variable instead of jquery's method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I learn jquery not long time. Help please to put variable instead object method.

```
return {
    label: item.MYVariable,
}
```

I need instead of `MYVariable` put dynamic variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can use bracket notation to access the variables, like this:

```
var foo = 'MYVariable';
return {
    label: item[foo];
}
```